# Atualização de coluna de uma tabela com dados de outra

Tags: sql-update

como consigo realizar esta atualização?

```
update estoque,tabcest
set estoque.cest=tabcest.cest 
where locate(trim(tabcest.ncm),estoque.ncm) 
and estoque.tipoproduto in ('produto','consumo') 
and estoque.cest is null;
```

está demorando, na realidade não está executando, servidor pára.
banco `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

funcionou, demourou um pouco
/* Conexão com 127.0.0.1 fechada em 2018-07-26 01:49:45 */
/* Registros afetados: 7.344  Registros encontrados: 0  Avisos: 0  Duração de 1 consulta: 00:09:11 */
/* Conectando em 127.0.0.1 via MySQL (TCP/IP), usuário root, usando a senha: No... */